# How to combine millions of large ranges that overlap cross series?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

I am trying to convert CSV text dumps of [MaxMind GeoLite2 database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data) into an efficient SQLite3 database with a lot of "laziness". I will spare you all the details, I have written a [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1koK3-r1UYFFgHvt030xDv4SgrN_bkoFz/view?usp=sharing) that almost does exactly what I want, but it failed to combine the ranges after many hours, so I was forced to terminate it.

I won't post the full script below, because very few people would read it and too much code might lose readers' attention.

---

At this stage, the problem can be simplified to finding all overlaps between lists of ranges that don't overlap intra-list but overlap inter-list. And they are guaranteed to be sorted. Let me show you what I mean.

I have many triplets in the form `(start, end, data)`, `start` & `end` are both `int`s and `start <= end`, and it is the compressed `dict`: `{k: data for k in range(start, end + 1)}`. **The numbers are huge, they are uint32 for IPv4 networks and uint128 for IPv6 networks, and I have 4,673,096 such triplets for IPv4 networks and 1,685,642 such triplets for IPv6 networks.**

So I need a really efficient solution for this problem.

---

The problem is simple, given two huge lists of triplets, in the form `(start, end, data)` representing `{k: data for k in range(start, end + 1)}`, the triplets in the same list don't overlap, repeatedly pop the first item from either lists when needed, until either or both is empty.

In each iteration compare the two current items from their respective lists to find overlaps between them. If there are overlaps, split the two ranges into non-overlapping ranges, the overlapping range should have attributes from both ranges and non-overlapping portion of the original ranges should be split from the overlapping portion.

We then yield the ranges that are past, a range is past if its end has been reached, meaning if the end of a range is greater than the other, its respective list shouldn't be popped in the next iteration, and if the ends are equal, then both lists need to be popped in the next iteration.

Given two triplets `(As, Ae, Ad)` and `(Bs, Be, Bd)`, in which `As <= Ae and Bs <= Be` must always be satisfied, if we add the constraint `As <= Bs`, there are a total of eight conditions that may affect the result of comparison, I have listed them below, the first return value means the ranges that are past, the second indicate the index of the positional argument that is the current range (if `Ae != Be`),  and the third the start of the current range after adjustment (if `Ae != Be`).

```
{
    ('Ae < Bs'): [[('As', 'Ae', '(Ad, )')], 1, 'Bs'],
    ('As == Bs', 'Ae == Be'): [[('As', 'Ae', '(Ad, Bd)')], None, None],
    ('As < Bs', 'Ae < Be'): [[('As', 'Bs - 1', '(Ad, )'), ('Bs', 'Ae', '(Ad, Bd)')], 1, 'Ae + 1'],
    ('As < Bs', 'Ae == Be'): [[('As', 'Bs - 1', '(Ad, )'), ('Bs', 'Ae', '(Ad, Bd)')], None, None],
    ('As == Bs', 'Ae < Be'): [[('As', 'Ae', '(Ad, Bd)')], 1, 'Ae + 1'],
    ('As < Bs', 'Be < Ae'): [[('As', 'Bs - 1', '(Ad, )'), ('Bs', 'Be', '(Ad, Bd)')], 0, 'Be + 1'],
    ('As < Bs', 'Be == Ae'): [[('As', 'Bs - 1', '(Ad, )'), ('Bs', 'Be', '(Ad, Bd)')], None, None],
    ('As == Bs', 'Be < Ae'): [[('Bs', 'Be', '(Ad, Bd)')], 0, 'Be + 1'],
}
```

---

There are 14 possibilities of the order and uniqueness of As, Ae, Bs and Be if As <= Bs, there are at most 28 possibilities. I have written a completely working script that is guaranteed to get the correct result, but unfortunately it is too slow:

```
from itertools import chain

def merge_worker(A, B):
    if cur := B[0] < A[0]:
        A, B = B, A

    (As, Ae, Ad), (Bs, Be, Bd) = A, B
    if Ae < Bs:
        return [(As, Ae, {Ad})], cur ^ 1, cur, (Bs, Be, Bd)

    if Ae < Be:
        cur ^= 1
        low, high, data = Ae, Be, Bd
    else:
        low, high, data = Be, Ae, Ad

    ranges = [(As, Bs - 1, {Ad})] if As < Bs else []
    ranges.append((Bs, low, {Ad, Bd}))
    return (
        (ranges, 1, 1, None)
        if Ae == Be
        else (ranges, cur, cur ^ 1, (low + 1, high, data))
    )


def merge_series(line_a, line_b):
    end_a = end_b = 1
    while line_a and line_b:
        range_a = line_a.pop(0) if end_a else current
        range_b = line_b.pop(0) if end_b else current
        past, end_a, end_b, current = merge_worker(range_a, range_b)
        yield past

    remaining = line_a or line_b
    end_b = 1
    while current and end_b and remaining:
        past, _, end_b, current = merge_worker(current, remaining.pop(0))
        yield past

    if current:
        yield [(*current[:2], {current[2]})]

    yield ((s, e, {d}) for s, e, d in remaining)


def merge(segments):
    start, end, data = next(segments)
    for start2, end2, data2 in segments:
        if data == data2 and end + 1 == start2:
            end = end2
        else:
            yield start, end, data
            start, end, data = start2, end2, data2
    yield start, end, data


def combine_series(line_a, line_b):
    return merge(chain.from_iterable(merge_series(line_a, line_b)))
```

The full script containing methods of test case generation and result verification is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wmqcKgdbA20VcMYdHxukKJVvVHEtn4fI/view?usp=sharing), I have rigorously verified the correctness of my solution.

But unfortunately it is way too slow:

```
In [393]: line_a = get_series(262144, 2**32, 2048, 'A')

In [394]: line_b = get_series(262144, 2**32, 2048, 'B')

In [395]: %time correct = list(combine_series(line_a, line_b))
CPU times: total: 46.6 s
Wall time: 49.5 s
```

For merely 524,288 triplets, it took around 50 seconds. I have literally millions of triplets to process. While it may be tempting to say for 4,673,096 triplets it will take 445.661 seconds, the reality is way more complicated, the execution time depends on the time complexity and data involved.

I don't know the exact structure of the actual data, and I don't know what the time complexity of my function is (I guess it's O(n)?), and I don't have enough RAM to generate million item test cases, I can't even sample 128-bit integers using `random.sample`:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

The method is way too slow and can't reliably process the whole data.

How can I scale it up using `Cython`, `NumPy`, `Numba` and the like? I have already tried `numba.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)` and it didn't work, I won't show the tracebacks here. How can I scale it up so that it can process millions of items relatively fast? Bear in mind I need to process IPv6 addresses which are 128 bit unsigned integers and not supported by C natively.

---

I originally thought `chain` will through some not supported data type exception when used with `numba.njit`, surprisingly it didn't in this case. I added `numba.njit(cache=True, fastmath=True)` in front of each of the three main generator functions, and there is no performance change at all, I then compiled the utility function, still no performance boost but no exception was thrown.

---

I have just found out that my new method is much slower than my previous method, and my previous method failed to process the whole data:

```
In [402]: line_a = get_series(262144, 2**32, 2048, 'A')

In [403]: line_b = get_series(262144, 2**32, 2048, 'B')

In [404]: %time correct = list(combine_series(line_a, line_b))
CPU times: total: 47.3 s
Wall time: 49.4 s

In [405]: line_a = get_series(262144, 2**32, 2048, 'A')

In [406]: line_b = get_series(262144, 2**32, 2048, 'B')

In [407]: %time correct = combine(line_a+line_b)
CPU times: total: 4.12 s
Wall time: 4.42 s
```

---

My intentions as requested by a commenter:

I am ethnic Chinese but I am also a left-liberal, I hate the authoritarian regime and I plan to immigrate to United States.

As for the purpose, I use VPNs and they tend to be blocked. So I plan to use hundreds of public DNS over HTTPS servers to find the actual IP addresses of blocked websites and unblock them.

I am going to do hundreds of DNS queries at once asynchronously, and then ping the resultant IP addresses all at once asynchronously, to find the IP addresses that are accessible, then change my hosts file to unblock the websites.

The information from the CSV files is crucial to the effort, first these DNS over HTTPS servers themselves may be blocked and/or hijacked, I need to use the geolocation of the IP addresses to determine the reliability of the DNS servers and the resultant IP addresses.

If the DNS is based in China, it isn't trustworthy; if the DNS isn't operated by the Chinese but a Chinese IP responded to the address, then the DNS server's domain name is hijacked; if the DNS is far from China, it should have a lower priority than closer ones, because the latency is likely higher.

If a resultant IP address is owned by the Chinese, don't ever ping it and don't ever use the DNS that returned it again; if multiple IP addresses in the same network are blocked, don't test other IP addresses from the same network; the IP addresses would be ranked according to the geolocation information, and if the top one gets blocked test the next best one and repeat, until there are no good IP addresses, then the DNS query should start all over again...

Comment: You might get more/better responses if you put a tl;dr at the top explaining the algorithmic problem without all the extraneous details.

Comment: In your last paragraph, what do you refer to as "new method" and "previous method", and how is it relevant for the question?

Comment: Are `line_a` and `line_b` lists? Have you considered making them deques? You repeatedly call `.pop(0)` on them, which is bad for lists.

Comment: Why can't you generate random 128-bit integers by `random.randrange(2 ** 128)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 But then I have to call `random.randrange(2**128)` for each number that needs to be generated, and that is obviously inefficient and the numbers aren't guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: I am currently trying to learn C++, and if I learned enough I will attempt to translate my Python code into C++ program and hopefully succeed. I expect this to take a few days. But then I would only be able to process IPv4 networks and not IPv6 which are uint128. I will post a question here when I finished IPv4 version of my program.

Comment: Nothing prevent you create a new type uint128 that behave like native integer in C++. Note there are libraries that implementing such a thing like GMP (quite heavy just for uint128 numbers) or Boost. In general, operating systems APIs provide data structure to store IPv4 and IPv6 address (basically a union and/or struct).

Comment: For motivation, you could disclose what use the result is put to.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to *How to combine ranges efficiently*,
but an attempt to more clearly see what's going on:

```
def overlap(A, B):
    if which := B[0] < A[0]:
        A, B = B, A

    (As, Ae, Ad), (Bs, Be, Bd) = A, B
    if Ae < Bs:
        return [(As, Ae, (Ad,))], which ^ 1, Bs

    if Ae < Be:
        which ^= 1
        low = Ae
    else:
        low = Be

    ranges = [(As, Bs - 1, (Ad,))] if As < Bs else []
    ranges.append((Bs, low, (Ad, Bd)))
    return (ranges, None, None) if Ae == Be else (ranges, which, low + 1)
```